# Issue with @ComponentScan, filters since migrating to javaconfig

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo, spring-java-config

I am trying to migrate to javaConfig using the following configuration:

**WebMvcConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.bignibou" }, useDefaultFilters = false, 
        includeFilters = {  @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class),
                            @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = ControllerAdvice.class) })
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(converter());
        addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    @Override
    protected void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(currentMemberHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/", "classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/");
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }

    @Override
    protected void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/cgv").setViewName("conditions/cgv");
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService() {
        return new ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean().getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter() {
        MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomJacksonObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new CustomJacksonObjectMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public CurrentMemberHandlerMethodArgumentResolver currentMemberHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
        return new CurrentMemberHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public FixedLocaleResolver fixedLocaleResolver() {
        FixedLocaleResolver fixedLocaleResolver = new FixedLocaleResolver();
        fixedLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
        return fixedLocaleResolver;

    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafTilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        ThymeleafTilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new ThymeleafTilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml", "/WEB-INF/web-templates/**/views.xml" });
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

}
```

**Main config**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.bignibou", 
excludeFilters = {  @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, value = RooRegexFilter.class),
                    @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class) })
public class MiscellaneousConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("META-INF/i18n/application", "META-INF/i18n/messages", "META-INF/i18n/mail-templates", "META-INF/i18n/validation-messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() throws IOException {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:META-INF/i18n/*.properties"));
        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ppc;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

And finally my **custom regex filter**:

```
public class RooRegexFilter extends RegexPatternTypeFilter {

    public RooRegexFilter() {
        super(Pattern.compile(".*_Roo_.*"));
    }

}
```

I get errors such as **BeanCreationException** and **NoSuchBeanDefinitionException** as follows:

```
nov. 03, 2013 3:58:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Grave: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchEngineController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bignibou.service.searchEngine.SearchEngineService com.bignibou.controller.searchEngine.SearchEngineController.searchEngineService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bignibou.service.searchEngine.SearchEngineService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:505)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bignibou.service.searchEngine.SearchEngineService com.bignibou.controller.searchEngine.SearchEngineController.searchEngineService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bignibou.service.searchEngine.SearchEngineService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bignibou.service.searchEngine.SearchEngineService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 28 more

nov. 03, 2013 3:58:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
Grave: La servlet /bignibou a généré une exception "load()"
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bignibou.service.searchEngine.SearchEngineService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:505)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I suspect something is wrong with my @ComponentScan configuration. Can anyone please help?

**edit 1**: here is my web.xml-equivalent:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        XmlWebApplicationContext rootContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.setConfigLocations(new String[] { "classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml" });

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.addListener(RequestContextListener.class);
        servletContext.addListener(HttpSessionEventPublisher.class);

        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr;
        fr = servletContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter());
        fr.setAsyncSupported(Boolean.TRUE);
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        fr.setAsyncSupported(Boolean.TRUE);
        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        fr = servletContext.addFilter("Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter", new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter());
        fr.setAsyncSupported(Boolean.TRUE);
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        fr = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy());
        fr.setAsyncSupported(Boolean.TRUE);
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        mvcContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("bignibou", new DispatcherServlet(mvcContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The best resource for Java Configuration is the Spring documentation.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)

It doesn't seem like you are registering your `MiscellaneousConfiguration` class anywhere. Change this bit

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MiscellaneousConfiguration.class);
servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
```

I don't know what your XML config was scanning for but apparently it wasn't adding a `SearchEngineService` bean to the context.  Since there is no `SearchEngineService` bean in the context to autowire into the `SearchEngineController` bean, context initialization will fail.

---

Note that only your servlet (`@WebMvc`) config should scan for `@Controller`. Make your `@ComponentScan` `basePackages` more specific so that bean definitions for the same class don't overwrite each other.

---

Also, you will want to make this `@Bean` method `static`

```
@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() throws IOException {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    ppc.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:META-INF/i18n/*.properties"));
    ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return ppc;
}
```

`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. You can read about why you have to do this in the [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) javadoc.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios. I thought an exclude filter would exclude @Controller annotated classes from being picked up and leave this for the webmvc config...

Comment: @balteo. WOOPs give me two minutes.

Comment: @balteo Please post your web.xml or `WebAppInitializer`.

Comment: @balteo Is the `MiscellaneousConfiguration` imported by the `applicationContext.xml`?

Comment: Actually MiscellaneousConfiguration is replacing the applicationContext.xml file...

Comment: I renamed applicationContext.xml into applicationContext.old so that it is no longer picked up by Spring...

Comment: @balteo What do you mean? Are you using an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` with the `ContextLoaderListener`? As it currently stands, it doesn't seem like your `MiscellaneousConfiguration` is being loaded anywhere.

Comment: I am trying to gradually replace each xml file by a javaconfig file. Is there anything wrong with my WebApplicationInitializer?

Comment: How come other XXConfiguration classes are taken into account and not the MiscellaneousConfiguration one? Am I missing something in the WebApplicationInitializer you reckon?

Comment: @balteo It doesn't work like that. You have to either component scan for the `@Configuration` classes or register them like you do here `mvcContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class);` See my edit. You can add an `@ImportResource` to import xml files if you need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sotirios: you said it all here: "You have to either component scan for the @Configuration classes or register them like you do here mvcContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class)"

Comment: @balteo You are welcome. Take note of the other little bits in my answer. Might save some headaches down the line. Of course, your best reference is the Spring documentation.