# how to exclude a package using @ComponentScan.Filter in java based configuration correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wanted to use Java configuration for my Spring MVC App and Converted root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.rhcloud.purejava">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
        id="entityManagerFactory">      
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.rhcloud.purejava.entity"></property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.rhcloud.purejava.repository"/>

</beans>
```

to RootConfigurer.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.rhcloud.purejava" }, 
excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter (type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, 
pattern = "com.rhcloud.purejava.controller")})
@EnableTransactionManagement 
@EnableJpaRepositories (basePackages = "com.rhcloud.purejava.repository")
public class RootConfigurer {   

    private Properties jpaProperties;   

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/java");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = 
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.rhcloud.purejava.entity");
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());

        jpaProperties = new Properties();       
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

I don't have any idea to set `@ComponentScan.Filter` correctly, because I'm getting

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.rhcloud.purejava.config.RootConfigurer]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter type not supported with String pattern: ANNOTATION
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:179)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:717)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter type not supported with String pattern: ANNOTATION
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.typeFiltersFor(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:107)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:229)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: @Jens how can I add filter for multiple classes?

Comment: Do you mean all classes in one package or two classes ?

Comment: All class in one package and found this `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.rhcloud.project" }, 
excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter (type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, 
pattern = "com.rhcloud.project.controller")})` adding `pattern` attribute is the choice?

Comment: @Jens I'm having exception please see my _edit_ and suggest a solution!

Comment: maybe you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754374/issue-with-componentscan-filters-since-migrating-to-javaconfig

Comment: @jpganz18 I want to exclude a package containing all controllers, the link provided is not satisfactory

Comment: is that package inside another package you actually want to include?

Comment: @jpganz18 look this is base package _com.rhcloud.purejava_ and controllers are _com.rhcloud.purejava.controller_ and services are _com.rhcloud.purejava.service_ so I want to exclude controllers as in `<context:component-scan base-package="com.rhcloud.purejava">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>`